# HSQLDB Query given two dates and time

Tags: hsqldb, libreoffice-base

I need to get the list of users from the date and time entered to the date and time left(but also give the results if no date and time entered). Something is wrong with the results of this query, especially when i type the date/time in/left. The search form works for the rest of the fields (like Name, Vehicle Number, Level, Unit).

```
SELECT * FROM "tblVehicles"
WHERE
((UPPER("Name") LIKE '%' ||

UPPER(:VAR_NAME) || '%')

OR

(:VAR_NAME is NULL))

AND

((UPPER("Vehicle Number") LIKE '%' ||

UPPER(:VAR_VEHICLE) || '%')

OR

(:VAR_VEHICLE is NULL))

AND

((UPPER("Level") LIKE '%' ||

UPPER(:VAR_LEVEL) || '%')

OR

(:VAR_LEVEL is NULL))

AND

((UPPER("Unit") LIKE '%' ||

UPPER(:VAR_UNIT) || '%')

OR

(:VAR_UNIT is NULL))

AND

((("Date In" >= :VAR_DATEIN) AND ("Time In" >= :VAR_TIMEIN))

OR

((:VAR_DATEIN is NULL)

OR

(:VAR_TIMEIN is NULL)))

AND

((("Date Left" <= :VAR_DATELEFT) AND ("Time Left" <= :VAR_TIMELEFT))



OR

((:VAR_DATELEFT is NULL)

OR

(:VAR_TIMELEFT is NULL)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Something is wrong with the results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the dates have not been entered in the correct format in the parameter input dialog.  As an example, create a new database with `tblVehicles` using the following schema.

[image: tblVehicles table design]

In the data entry dialog, right-click on date columns and format as `YYYY-MM-DD`, and time columns `HH:MM`.  These formats are the least ambiguous.  Then enter the following data.

[image: table data entry]

Now create the following query in SQL view.

```
SELECT * FROM "tblVehicles"
WHERE ((("Date In" >= :VAR_DATEIN) AND ("Time In" >= :VAR_TIMEIN))
    OR ((:VAR_DATEIN is NULL)
    OR (:VAR_TIMEIN is NULL)))
AND ((("Date Left" <= :VAR_DATELEFT) AND ("Time Left" <= :VAR_TIMELEFT))
    OR ((:VAR_DATELEFT is NULL)
    OR (:VAR_TIMELEFT is NULL)))
```

Then run the query.  Enter `2017-02-01` for VAR_DATEIN which autocorrects to `#02/01/2017`.  Enter `8:00` for VAR_TIMEIN which autocorrects to `#08:00:00#`.

[image: query parameters]

The result:

[image: query output]

There is a FAQ for Base that describes date ranges: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Base/122.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer on your question, but rather an observations and suggestion about technique.  Most if not all of us today have wide screens which can easily accommodate long text lines.  I suggest you use a good editor and make it wide, and then align your logic in columns as I have done for you below, so that you can more easily see what you are doing.  (In other words, copy and paste the SQL below, into your wide text editor, so you can see what it looks like there.)

You will note that I have used 2 spaces for outer parens, and 1 space for next in, and 0 spaces for inner most parens.  Also I have aligned things so it's easy to see that this is a big set of ANDs made up of ORs.

It was a very long time ago when I was introduced to such formatting.  They called it "pretty printing" at the time.  It has served me well over the years.  Seems like programmers have largely forgotten this simple method, but I hope you can use it.  Sometimes logic is complex, and the most important thing is to easily see how it works.

.Good luck to you!

```
SELECT * FROM "tblVehicles"
WHERE 
(  (  UPPER("Name"          ) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:VAR_NAME   ) || '%'   ) OR   (:VAR_NAME     is NULL)                               ) AND
(  (  UPPER("Vehicle Number") LIKE '%' || UPPER(:VAR_VEHICLE) || '%'   ) OR   (:VAR_VEHICLE  is NULL)                               ) AND
(  (  UPPER("Level"         ) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:VAR_LEVEL  ) || '%'   ) OR   (:VAR_LEVEL    is NULL)                               ) AND
(  (  UPPER("Unit"          ) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:VAR_UNIT   ) || '%'   ) OR   (:VAR_UNIT     is NULL)                               ) AND

(  ( ("Date In"   >= :VAR_DATEIN  ) AND ("Time In"   >= :VAR_TIMEIN  ) ) OR ( (:VAR_DATEIN   is NULL) OR (:VAR_TIMEIN   is NULL) )  ) AND
(  ( ("Date Left" <= :VAR_DATELEFT) AND ("Time Left" <= :VAR_TIMELEFT) ) OR ( (:VAR_DATELEFT is NULL) OR (:VAR_TIMELEFT is NULL) )  )
```

Comment: Nowadays most programmers do not like all of the extra spaces because it requires too much work when someone else has to make changes.
Views on long lines vary and may depend on the language.  I prefer limiting width to 79 characters, the standard in the Python community.  However, often people write in languages such as Java using wide-screen style.

Comment: The fact is there are 64 parens in the question's SQL, and no easy way to simplify it.  

While I think "most programmers do not..." agree on anything, in this case I think that most programmers would agree that this would be a very hard piece of SQL to maintain.  

So for all of you who want to stick to arbitrary, and antique hardware limits of say 80 characters, (yes, I owned several terminals that were limited to 80 character widths, and even once developed on Amiga and Commodore that were limited to 40), these days we should be using the best most powerful tools available.  Wide is in.

Comment: Notice that the SQL code in my answer can be read without needing to scroll back and forth.  It looks like stackoverflow.com agrees with using limited width.  :)  Also, "these days we should be using the best most powerful tools available."  Yes, like two windows of code that can be read side-by-side on one screen without scrolling horizontally, and text editors that can insert 40 `*` symbols with only 5 keystrokes (`40i*<Esc>` in my editor).

Comment: By the way, my reference to "most programmers" may have been somewhat ambiguous.  I was basically rewording your statement "Seems like programmers have largely forgotten this simple method."  My (perhaps too subtle) point was that it has been a purposeful moving away from aligning code with spaces, not a matter of forgetting.  This is different from the situation with line width, on which there is no current consensus.

Comment: Stackoverflow has no width limits and I wasn't referring to your SQL.  And sorry to hear you're also stuck with vim.  Would love to see something like Notepad++ on linux in the future.  I used it for a couple of years and I think it blows vim out of the water.